# How to write LINQ queries against a facade wrapping a WCF Data Service?

Tags: .net, linq, expression, wcf-data-services

I am developing a Silverlight application pulls data down from a WCF Data Service however communication with the service sits behind a facade.  I did this to facilitate development of the SL app without the server being implemented yet so the SL app could consume data from txt files and not know the difference.

The interfaces below make up the facade and the concrete classes are their implementation behind the facade.

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    IEntityQuery<IRootEntity> Roots { get; }
    IEntityQuery<IBranchEntity> Branches{ get; }
    IEntityQuery<ILeafEntity> Leaves { get; }
}

public interface IEntityQuery<TEntity> : IQueryable<TModel>
{
    IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    IEnumerable<TModel> EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
    IEntityQuery<TModel> Where(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);
}

public interface IEntityCollection<TEntity> : INotifyCollectionChanged,
    INotifyPropertyChanged, IQueryable<TModel>
{

}

public interface IRootEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IModelCollection<IBranchEntity> Branches { get; set; }
}

public interface IBranchEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IRootEntity Root { get; set; }
    IModelCollection<ILeafEntity> Leaves { get; set; }
}

public interface ILeafEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IBranchEntity Branch { get; set; }
}

// Partially implemented by me and partially by Visual Studio when the Service
// Reference was added.
public partial class Container : IDataContext
{
    IEntityQuery<IRootEntity> IDataContext.Roots 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return new ModelQuery<IRootEntity, RootEntity>(this.Roots); 
        }
    }

    IEntityQuery<IBranchEntity> IDataContext.Branches
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return new ModelQuery<IBranchEntity, BranchEntity>(this.Roots); 
        }
    }

    IEntityQuery<ILeafEntity> IDataContext.Leaves
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return new ModelQuery<ILeafEntity, LeafEntity>(this.Leaves); 
        }
    }
}

public class EntityQuery<TFacade, TConcrete>
    where TConcrete : class, TFacade
{
    private DataServiceQuery<TConcrete> _dsq;

    public ModelQuery(DataServiceQuery<TConcrete> dsq)
    {
        _dsq = dsq;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return _dsq.BeginExecute(callback, state);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TFacade> EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        return _dsq.EndExecute(asyncResult).AsEnumerable() as IEnumerable<TFacade>;
    }

    public IModelQuery<TFacade> Where(Expression<Func<TFacade, bool>> predicate)
    {
        Expression<Func<TConcrete, bool>> concretePredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TConcrete, bool>>(predicate.Body, predicate.Parameters);
        return new ModelQuery<TFacade, TConcrete>(_dsq.Where(concretePredicate) as DataServiceQuery<TConcrete>);
    }

    // IQueryable implementation ...
}

public class EntityCollection<TFacade, TConcrete> : IEntityCollection<TFacade>
    where TConcrete : class, TFacade
{
    public EntityCollection(ObservableCollection<TConcrete> innerCollection)
    {
        this.InnerCollection = innerCollection;
        this.InnerCollection.CollectionChanged += InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<TConcrete> InnerCollection { get; private set; }

    private void InnerCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    // IQueryable<TFacade> implementation ...
}

// Partially implemented by me and partially by Visual Studio when the Service
// Reference was added.
public partial class RootEntity : IRootEntity
{   
    IList<IBranchEntity> IRootEntity.Branches
    {
        get { return this.Branches; }
        set { this.Branches = value as IList<IBranchEntity>; }
    }
}

// Partially implemented by me and partially by Visual Studio when the Service
// Reference was added.
public partial class BranchEntity : IBranchEntity 
{   
    IRootEntity IBranchEntity.Root
    {
        get { return this.Root; }
        set { this.Root = value as RootEntity; }
    }

    IList<ILeafEntity> IBranchEntity.Leaves
    {
        get { return this.Leaves; }
        set { this.Leaves = value as IList<LeafEntity>; }
    }
}

// Partially implemented by me and partially by Visual Studio when the Service
// Reference was added.
public partial class LeafEntity : ILeafEntity 
{   
    IRootEntity ILeafEntity.Root
    {
        get { return this.Root; }
        set { this.Root = value as RootEntity; }
    }
}
```

The `EntityQuery` and `EntityCollection` classes became necessary to maintain the abstraction of the facade.  Without them, the SL app would have to know about `DataServiceQuery` and `DataServiceCollection`.

The problem I am having is in translating LINQ queries written by the SL app developer against the facade into a LINQ query that the client-side WCF Data Service proxy can translate into an OData URL.

I've been able to run some simple queries but the more complex ones start throwing exceptions.  The query that is currently giving me a problem is the following:

```
IEntityQuery<IRootEntity> query = this.Context.Roots
    .Where(r => r.Branches.Any(b=> b.Leaves.Any(l => l.Name == "Find Me")));

IRootEntity result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => query.BeginExecute(null, null))
    .ContinueWith(t => query.EndExecute(t.Result))
    .Result
    .Single();
```

I get a `NotSupportedException` stating that "The source parameter for the 'Any' method has to be either a navigation or a collection property."  I'm pretty sure this is because `Any()` is being called on a `ModelCollection<T1,T2>` instead of on the `DataServiceCollection<T>` that's its InnerCollection, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is long (good question though) but the answer is short. You can't expose `IQueryable` and expect that its [leaky abstractions](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/) won't hurt you.

In the end the interface is backed by [`DataServiceQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646677.aspx). There's a long list of LINQ methods that are not supported: [LINQ Considerations (WCF Data Services): see Unsupported LINQ Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx). Besides that, `DataServiceQuery` has instance methods that are useful, but can't be exploited by your interface, like `Expand`.

I'm afraid this requires a major overhaul of your architecture: expose methods that accept specifications and translate these to supported linq queries *behind* the façade.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if this is the answer yet but it was still very informative.